# Spring UnexpectedRollbackException in nested @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a dao class (`MyDao`) which is marked with `@Transactional` annotaion (on class level) with no additional parameters. In this dao class I have a method which in some case needs to throw a checked exception and perform a transaction rollback. Something like this:

```
@Transactional
public class MyDao {

    public void daoMethod() throws MyCheckedException() {

        if (somethingWrong) {
            TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
            throw new MyCheckedException("something wrong");
        }
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, this dao method is called from a service method, which is also marked as @Transactional:

```
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Transactional
    public void serviceMethod() throws MyCheckedException {
        myDao.daoMethod();
    }

}
```

The problem is that when `daoMethod()` is called from `serviceMethod()` and marks the transaction as rollback only, I get an `UnexpectedRollbackException`.

Under the hood, Spring creates two transactional interceptors: one for `MyDao` and one for `MyService`. When `daoMethod()` marks the transaction for rollback, the interceptor for `MyDao` performs the rollback and returns. But then the stack moves to the interceptor for `MyService`, which finds out about the previous rollback, and throws the `UnexpectedRollbackException`.

One solution would be to remove the `@Transactional` annotation from MyDao. But this is not feasible right now because `MyDao` is used at a lot of places and this could cause errors.

Another solution would be to not set the transaction as rollback only in `daoMethod()` but rather mark `serviceMethod()` to revert the transaction on `MyCheckedException`. But I don't like this solution because I have a lot of these "service methods" and I would have to mark all of them explicitly to rollback on that exception. Also everyone who would add a new service method in the future would have to think of this and therefore it creates opportunities for errors.

Is there a way I could keep setting the transaction as rollback only from `daoMethod()` and prevent Spring from throwing the `UnexpectedRollbackException`? For instance, with some combination of parameters `isolation` and `propagation`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I have to explicitly tell also the "outer" interceptor, that I want to rollback the transaction. In other words, **both** interceptors need to be "informed" about the rollback. This means either catching `MyCheckedException` in `serviceMethod()` and setting the transaction status to rollback only, or to mark `serviceMethod()` like this `@Transactional(rollbackFor=MyCheckedException.class)`.

But as I mentioned in the OP, I want to avoid this because it's prone to errors. Another way is to make `@Transactional` rollback on `MyCheckedException` by default. But that's a [completely different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495821/spring-define-custom-transactional-behavior-in-java-config).

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception inside the transaction already trigger a rollback, using setRollbackOnly() is redundant here and that's probably why you have that error.

If the Transactionnal on the DAO is set up with Propagation.REQUIRED which is the default, then it will reuse an existing transaction if there is already one or create one if there is none. Here it should reuse the transaction created at the service layer.

Comment: Spring only rollbacks transaction on runtime exceptions by default. This can be modified by attribute `rollbackFor` on the @Transactional annotation. But when I do it on MyDao, I get the same result as setting the transaction status.

Comment: You should use the framework configuration to rollback on checked exception instead of changing the transaction status manually, you can set rollbackFor on Exception.class to rollback on all checked exceptions. And you can put this on all your services (or create an annotation with that configuration that you can use instead).

Comment: You can also put the checked exception inside a runtime exception and throw it instead. I don't know your use case here, but it could be a solution.

Comment: My problem isn't "How to rollback the transaction". My problem is that when I have two "nested" interceptors, the inner interceptor performs the rollback and later the outer interceptor throws UnexpectedRollbackException. The way I tell Spring to perform the rollback doesn't matter.